# Nested procedure - Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT

Tags: sql-server-2008

I get an error

```
Custom error message. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
```

My SQL Code is following

**Procedure 1**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProcedure1] 
    @Id int
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

EXEC spProcedure2 @Id

-- Code ommited, Next procedures execution

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    -- Code ommited, saving error to Log table

    RAISERROR(@errorMessage, @errorSeverity, @errorState);
END CATCH
END
```

**Procedure 2**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProcedure2]
     @Id int
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY

    -- Check if record exists
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table t WHERE t.Id = @Id)
    BEGIN
        -- stop procedure due to user error
        RAISERROR('Custom error message.',16,1)
        RETURN
    END

    -- Code ommited, DML operation

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    -- Code ommited, saving error to Log table

    RAISERROR(@errorMessage, @errorSeverity, @errorState);
END CATCH
END
```

I am not sure how to handle transaction in the Procedure 2 to obey this error ?

Comment: A strong possibility is that you end up raising an error from a procedure which is not caught by the catch, and thereby you'll never rollback.

Comment: I tried to add Rollback before RAISERROR('Custom error message.',16,1) but the message is the same

Comment: You shouldn't rollback in procedure2 unless you start transactions in procedure2.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: I am not, I only tried it to solve the original error, but it did not help, but at least I know why it did not help :-)